# Shortest way to get matched patterns from a string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have pretty long string to parse, that looks like that (part of it)

```
$string = 'FIRM_ID = MC0356400000; TAG = EQTV; CURR_CODE = SUR; CLIENT_CODE = FR334; LIMIT_KIND = 1; OPEN_BALANCE = 4822.84; OPEN_LIMIT = 0.00; LEVERAGE = 0;'
```

I need to get values for php variables from that string, which I do with preg_match:

```
 preg_match("/FIRM_ID = (.*?);/", $string, $m);
 $firm_id = trim($m[1]);

 preg_match("/CLIENT_CODE = (.*?);/", $string, $m);
 $client_code = trim($m[1]);
```

... and so on

I was wondering is there a way to do the same in one line? May be with preg_replace or other functions, so I would not have to declare $m variable first and then take out from that [1] element.

So the code supposed to look like

```
 $firm_id = somefunction($string);
 $client_code = somefunction($string);
```

Its not practical question, more theoretical. I know how to get result that I need, I want to know if there is a simpler and more elegant way.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe something like `(\S+)\h=\h([^;]+)` with `preg_match_all` then use `group` 1 and `group 2`..or you could use variable variables..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match and capture key-value pairs and then combine into an array:

```
$re = '/(\w+)\s*=\s*([^;]*)/';
$str = 'FIRM_ID = MC0356400000; TAG = EQTV; CURR_CODE = SUR; CLIENT_CODE = FR334; LIMIT_KIND = 1; OPEN_BALANCE = 4822.84; OPEN_LIMIT = 0.00; LEVERAGE = 0;';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r(array_combine($matches[1],$matches[2]));
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/egrziC), result:

```
Array
(
    [FIRM_ID] => MC0356400000
    [TAG] => EQTV
    [CURR_CODE] => SUR
    [CLIENT_CODE] => FR334
    [LIMIT_KIND] => 1
    [OPEN_BALANCE] => 4822.84
    [OPEN_LIMIT] => 0.00
    [LEVERAGE] => 0
)
```

The regex is

```
/(\w+)\s*=\s*([^;]*)/
```

See is [demo online](https://regex101.com/r/xlOydu/1).

**Details**:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with optional whitespace(s)
- `([^;]*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than `;`.

To "initialize" the variables each at a time, you may use a

```
$var_name = 'FIRM_ID';
$re = '/' . $var_name . '\s*=\s*\K[^;]*/';
$str = 'FIRM_ID = MC0356400000; TAG = EQTV; CURR_CODE = SUR; CLIENT_CODE = FR334; LIMIT_KIND = 1; OPEN_BALANCE = 4822.84; OPEN_LIMIT = 0.00; LEVERAGE = 0;';
preg_match($re, $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/5lqLNl).

The `\K` is the match reset operator that omits all text matched so far within the current match iteration.

Comment: really neat! not exactly what I've asked for but definetly good

Comment: @DenisMatafonov: Did you ask for https://regex101.com/r/iDWWwy/1? However, using a `preg_replace` this way may cause too much backtracking and that will cause slow down. I'd still advise using `preg_match` then. Or do you just want to get rid of 2 items in the array?

Comment: @DenisMatafonov: You may use a solution like [this](http://ideone.com/5lqLNl) to just get the value into a 1-item array.

Comment: This solution is the most elegant

Answer (score 3):

If you remove spaces and replace `;` with `&`, you can do this:

```
parse_str(str_replace([' ', ';'], ['', '&'], $string), $result);
```

Which yields an easy to use associative array:

```
Array
(
    [FIRM_ID] => MC0356400000
    [TAG] => EQTV
    [CURR_CODE] => SUR
    [CLIENT_CODE] => FR334
    [LIMIT_KIND] => 1
    [OPEN_BALANCE] => 4822.84
    [OPEN_LIMIT] => 0.00
    [LEVERAGE] => 0
)
```

So just `echo $result['FIRM_ID'];`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `list` function after `preg_match_all` :

```
preg_match_all('/(\w[\w-]*)\h*=\h*([^;\h]+);/', $string, $matches);

list($firmId, $tag, $currCode, $clientCode, $limitKind, $openBalance, $openLimit, $leverage) = $matches[2];

echo $firmId;
//=> MC0356400000
echo $tag;
//=> EQTV
echo $clientCode;
//=> FR334
echo $openBalance;
//=> 4822.84
```

Comment: Hopefully there are always exactly 8 matches ;-)

Comment: One can use partial list as well e.g. `list($firmId, $tag, $currCode, $clientCode, $limitKind, $openBalance)`